# How to find the leftmost column of a data frame with all zeros in columns to the right with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(v1=c(0,1), v2=c(0,1),v3=c(0,1), v4=c(0,1) ) %>% 
    expand(v1,v2,v3,v4)
df

# A tibble: 16 x 4
    var1  var2  var3  var4
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     0     0     0     0
 2     0     0     0     1
 3     0     0     1     0
 4     0     0     1     1
 5     0     1     0     0
 6     0     1     0     1
 7     0     1     1     0
 8     0     1     1     1
 9     1     0     0     0
10     1     0     0     1
11     1     0     1     0
12     1     0     1     1
13     1     1     0     0
14     1     1     0     1
15     1     1     1     0
16     1     1     1     1
```

For each row, I would like to identify the leftmost column that contains a zero, such that all columns to the right also contain 0s. The expected output is as follows:

```
# A tibble: 16 x 5
    var1  var2  var3  var4 result
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> 
 1     0     0     0     0 var1  
 2     0     0     0     1 NA    
 3     0     0     1     0 var4  
 4     0     0     1     1 NA    
 5     0     1     0     0 var3  
 6     0     1     0     1 NA    
 7     0     1     1     0 var4  
 8     0     1     1     1 NA    
 9     1     0     0     0 var2  
10     1     0     0     1 NA    
11     1     0     1     0 var4  
12     1     0     1     1 NA    
13     1     1     0     0 var3  
14     1     1     0     1 NA    
15     1     1     1     0 var4  
16     1     1     1     1 NA
```

If possible, I would prefer a tidyverse solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution passes each row of values to a helper function using `dplyr::c_across()`; the helper function then uses `rle()` to return the start of the last run of zeros, if the last value is zero, and `NA` otherwise.

```
library(dplyr)

find_zero <- function(x, cols) {
  x_rle <- rle(x)
  if (tail(x_rle$values, 1) != 0) NA
  else rev(cols)[[tail(x_rle$lengths, 1)]]
}

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(result = find_zero(c_across(v1:v4), names(.))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

```
# A tibble: 16 × 5
      v1    v2    v3    v4 result
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> 
 1     0     0     0     0 v1    
 2     0     0     0     1 <NA>  
 3     0     0     1     0 v4    
 4     0     0     1     1 <NA>  
 5     0     1     0     0 v3    
 6     0     1     0     1 <NA>  
 7     0     1     1     0 v4    
 8     0     1     1     1 <NA>  
 9     1     0     0     0 v2    
10     1     0     0     1 <NA>  
11     1     0     1     0 v4    
12     1     0     1     1 <NA>  
13     1     1     0     0 v3    
14     1     1     0     1 <NA>  
15     1     1     1     0 v4    
16     1     1     1     1 <NA>
```

Answer (score 3):

I've no idea about a tidyverse solution, but here's a base R answer:

```
chk <- simplify2array(rev(Reduce(`+`, rev(df), accumulate=TRUE))) == 0
df$name <- names(df)[max.col(chk, "first")]
df$name[rowSums(chk) == 0] <- NA
df

### A tibble: 16 × 5
##      v1    v2    v3    v4 name 
##   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
## 1     0     0     0     0 v1   
## 2     0     0     0     1 NA   
## 3     0     0     1     0 v4   
## 4     0     0     1     1 NA   
## 5     0     1     0     0 v3   
## 6     0     1     0     1 NA   
## 7     0     1     1     0 v4   
## 8     0     1     1     1 NA   
## 9     1     0     0     0 v2   
##10     1     0     0     1 NA   
##11     1     0     1     0 v4   
##12     1     0     1     1 NA   
##13     1     1     0     0 v3   
##14     1     1     0     1 NA   
##15     1     1     1     0 v4   
##16     1     1     1     1 NA
```